# Increase speed of TCP traffic from A to B

Tags: networking, internet, internet-speed

I have read about and used software which claims to lower your in-game ping by rerouting the traffic from your client to the gameserver by using some kind of private network and sophisticated algorithms.

I would need to apply something like this to normal TCP traffic. Say I want to send a message from Australia to Denmark and want to achieve the hightest possible speed between sending and receiving the message. Are there services or techniques to maximize the speed of traffic?

Comment: Ping uses ICMP, not TCP. Those are two completely separate protocols.

Comment: Well, it is supposed to also reduce lag. That would mean the UDP traffic is sped up. If thats possible, it should also be possible to increase TCP speed.

Comment: "_That would mean the UDP traffic is sped up._" No, ICMP is a completely separate protocol than UDP. Ping, and any ICMP, can be routed differently than either TCP or UDP, both of which can be routed differently than the other. In fact, many ISPs will route ICMP and traceroute differently than other traffic in order to keep people from discovering their internal network structure. Some do it to make their networks look better than they are. You simply cannot compare one protocol to another protocol like that.

Comment: You would only be able to affect your local network to the internet provider. You wouldn't be able to speed up anything Beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

Normal ISPs usually optimise primerally for cost, then for bandwidth with latency being a distant third.

If you want the lowest possible latency, you want that latency reliablly and money is no object then your best option would be to rent a private link along the lowest latency path you can find. That is what for example the high frequency trading guys do.

The services offered for gamers are a compromise, you rent space on someone elses low latency network and then use your regular ISP links to connect to local PoPs operated by the low latency network. This can give better latency than your regular ISP connection though there is no gaurantee. If the latency problem is in your ISPs local access network rather than in the international transit links they buy then such services will not help.

I see no technical reason why these services could not be used for any protocol. I have not researched whether their terms and conditions allow it or not.